# SpringBoot + AWS cognito, can't resolve issuerUri

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, oauth-2.0, amazon-cognito

I wanted to create a sample Spring Boot application using AWS cognito for authorization. I was following several tutorials but always ended with the same error.

When I run the application, I get:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'httpSecurity': Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.HttpSecurityConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setContentNegotiationStrategy' parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setConfigurers' parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.OAuth2ClientConfiguration$OAuth2ClientWebMvcSecurityConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setAuthorizedClientManager' parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'OAuth2AuthorizedClientManager': Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2AuthorizedClientManager]: Factory method 'getAuthorizedClientManager' threw exception with message: Error creating bean with name 'clientRegistrationRepository' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/security/oauth2/client/servlet/OAuth2ClientRegistrationRepositoryConfiguration.class]:Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.registration.InMemoryClientRegistrationRepository]: Factory method 'clientRegistrationRepository' threw exception with message: Unable to resolve Configuration with the provided Issuer of "https://cognito-idp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/us-east-1_9EmaXexYM/.well-known/openid-configuration"
```

This seems to me weird because when I access directly in the browser the URL https://cognito-idp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/us-east-1_9EmaXexYM/.well-known/openid-configuration , I get a response with all the information. What could be the problem?

My application.yml:

```
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          cognito:
            clientName: SpringBootApp
            client-secret: 11iflp3rhfuj9veomalbsvoi5url4vhu3r39in5l1jo0btsac48s
            redirect-uri: 'http://localhost:8080/login/oauth2/code/cognito'
            client-id: 3ai0tn07c5smcn00d963670rsf
            scope: openid
            authorization-grant-type: authorization_code
        provider:
          cognito:
            issuerUri: https://cognito-idp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/us-east-1_9EmaXexYM/.well-known/openid-configuration
```

Comment: I updated the example on the AWS Github repo. I will post it here soon. It works perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [OpenID configuration you link](https://cognito-idp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/us-east-1_9EmaXexYM/.well-known/openid-configuration):

`"issuer":"https://cognito-idp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/us-east-1_9EmaXexYM"`

Issuer URI is not the same as the OpenID configuration URI: it does not contain `/.well-known/openid-configuration` (so remove that suffix from the `issuer` value in your conf)

Comment: I do have the correct URL. You just need to scroll to the right, as it doesn't fit all in here ;)

Comment: No you don't have the correct issuer URI.

Comment: Sorry, my bad! I misunderstood your message. You were right! Thanks!

Comment: By the way, I have written quite a few tutorials wich are kept updated with latest Boot versions: https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials